# Default value for null fields in a Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, textfield, ireport

### Background

A ResultSet has many `Double` value fields (with patterns like `"###0.000"`). Some values can be `null`.

### Problem

I want to replace `null` values with `"N/A"`, which is a `String` and cannot print to a Double field. Printing `"0.00"` for `null` values is unacceptable.

Using an PrintWhenExpression value of `($F{value} != null) ? $F{value} : "N/A"` does not work; it is not possible to use patterns in that way.

### Idea

Add hidden fields that write "N/A". These fields will be printed only if value is `null`.

### Question

Is there a better solution, and if so, what is it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Solution #1

Your solution:

1. Use a regular Double field (`doubleField`) for the column value.
2. Add a static String text field at the same location.
3. Change the Double field to **Blank When Null**.
4. Set the **PrintWhenExpression** value for the String text field to: `$F{doubleField} == null`.

#### Solution #2

The problem is, as you pointed out, that a Double and a String are two different data types. You can assign a String variable to the value of the Double using an appropriate expression. Then use the String variable as the field. The expression might resemble:

```
($F{doubleField} == null) ?
  "N/A" : new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.##").format($F{doubleField})
```

(Note: My preference is to use `==` instead of `!=`. Think positive.)

#### Solution #3

Change the SQL statement to pre-format the Double as a text string, and use the "N/A" in the string (by using a `CASE` or `DECODE` statement in the query).

Avoid this solution, though, as it is not maintainable.

#### Recommendation

Do not hard-code the "N/A" string throughout the report(s); put the "N/A" text in a constant, or a parameter with a default value of "N/A".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realized that it is possible to write an expression like: $F{value} != null ? String.format("%.3f", $F{value}) : "N/A" (or a constant for "N/A")

Comment: And also i see that it is possible to use java.text.DecimalFormat. thanks a lot for the 3 solutions that are explained well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this in your field expression:

```
("Your static text "+(($F{field}!=null)?$F{field}:""))
```

Or, if you don't want your static text to be visible when the field is null, try putting `$F{field}!=null` in your `PrintWhenExpression`.